# What does fill=..level.. mean in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I want to create a "heating map" for a dataset, which contains obs about shooting in NYC Boroughs.

```
ggmap(nyc_map)+
  stat_density2d(data = NYPD,
                 aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill= ..level..), 
                 alpha=0.08,
                 bins=30,
                 geom = "polygon") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green", name="Shootings level") + 
  scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.08), guide = "none") +
  scale_size(range = c(0,0.75)) +
  ggtitle("Shootings for Boroughs")+
  
  
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        legend.position="right") +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

In that case, what does `fill=..level..` means?? Because I don't have a variable for the number of shootings, I have the number of rows and the lat and long for Boroughs.
Should `fill=..level..` mean about mean of the shootings?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot-dot notation `..some_var..` allows to access statistics computed by ggplot to construct the plot. In this case, the levels for the 2d-density. You can, instead, extract and use them with `stat()`: [see related question on RStudio community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/documentation-for-computed-variables/38426)

Comment: yes, but I don't find any documentation that explains how level is calculated. 
I want to know this.. 
In the map, I have, for example, 75% of concentration in Brooklyn and also 75% in Bronx

Comment: The level is calculated with the `kde2d` function of package MASS (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MASS/versions/7.3-55/topics/kde2d). There's no separate variable 'shooting count' or similar. Rather, each coordinate pair indicates one shooting, and R calculates the spatial density from the number of observations per square unit (whose size you specify, e.g., through the `bins` argument).